# How to load http://debug.build.phonegap.com asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to load phonegaps debugging tools asynchronously.

If i include this in the script:

```
<script src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber" />
```

It will run correctly, if I load this:

```
$.getScript('http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber');
```

Then the code will not run correctly and will post nothing with its requests.

Comment: You can't do the second thing because of the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The onle way of getting something cross-domain by javascript is by JSONP.

Comment: beerrrr, good point. I do believe that once you are running it from your app however that this does not come into effect.

Comment: @RichardA `<script>` elements aren't bound by the SOP, which is why JSONP uses them. And, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is another option, though both it and JSONP require server-side support.

Comment: also, running this in your console you'll see its not restriced from cross domains.

Comment: It appears that it has something to do with the js that I am loading then posts to a different url and the first url is not getting the value of `#hutber` from my ajax... Could be something to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `async` attribute to the script-tag, as long as you only debug in [newer broswers](http://caniuse.com/script-async).

```
<script src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber" async></script>
```

Comment: I guess this would be the next best thing to do without too much configuration.

Comment: This does work on my desktop browser, however it doesn't seem to work when running via my app. Which is ultimately the reason for doing it. Maybe phonegap's debug can't work async'd :O

Comment: Are you debugging in a version of Android earlier than 3.0? According to Can I use, it should be working in the Android browser from 3.0. Also, have you tried just moving the script tag to the button of the body? This way, the page should be rendered when it loads.

Comment: Yep, running andriod 4.1.2. Good point. But in phonegap you can't seem to include full http requests in the index.html file. It fails every time./

Comment: Have you tried this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide_android ?